# Efficient way to find number of files in directory

Tags: c++

I am in a situation where I repeatedly need to know how many files are in any given directory with-in my directory structure. However, due to memory constraints on devices, I cannot keep an in-memory index of the number of files in all directories. 
From what I can tell based on the STL documentation, my option something along these lines:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::string path = ".";

    size_t count = 0;
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        ++count;
    }
    std::cout << "Number of files in dir \".\" is: " << count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Though it is fairly efficient code, I was wondering if there is not a faster way, that maybe even eliminates the usage of the `foreach`?

I am using C++17 if that helps and the code will run on macOS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Linux, NetBSD. Where the memory constraint is for devices running Linux and NetBSD. I have rougly 16kB of memory total on some of these devices.

Comment: Unrelated: If I'm not horribly mistaken this code is counting the directories in the directory in addition to the files .

Comment: @user4581301, if you want to constrain to just _regular files_, then we'd want to also ignore symlinks, device files, sockets and fifos.  Oh, and identify which names refer to the same inode ("hard links"), too.  That's not usually what people mean by counting files - that's usually a synonym for "directory entries" or "file names".

Comment: Is using Qt an option?

Comment: @user4581301 yes, it is intended. As they are files :)

Comment: @AlexanderS wauw I had not found that post thanks a milion.

Comment: @Ayxan no QT is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is no easy way.. while documentation says that there are begin and end defined for directory_iterator, it doesn't behave like a range-based one.

> ```
> directory_iterator begin( directory_iterator iter ) noexcept;
> (1)   (since C++17)
>
> directory_iterator end( const directory_iterator& ) noexcept;
> (2)   (since C++17)
> ```
>
> 1) Returns `iter` unchanged
>
> 2) Returns a default-constructed
>   `directory_iterator`, which serves as the end iterator. The argument is
>   ignored. These non-member functions enable the use of
>   `directory_iterators` with range-based for loops.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::directory_iterator a(".");

    for(auto& p: a)
        std::cout << p.path() << '\n';

    //std::cout << (std::end(a) - std::begin(a)) << '\n'; // apparently impossible,
    std::cout << 
              std::distance(a, 
                            fs::directory_iterator()) << '\n'; // always returns 1
    std::cout << 
              std::distance(fs::directory_iterator("."), 
                          fs::directory_iterator{}) << '\n'; // need a new iterator
}
```

Whenever you increment directory_iterator, it WILL NOT be equal to default constructed unless you reach the end of list. Increment operator is the "magic" which scans file system for next entry. The way to do this using standard library is:

```
fs::directory_iterator a(".");
int count = 0;
for(auto p: a) {
    ++count;
}
std::cout << count << '\n';
```

This is exactly what `std::distance` does. The state of iterator changes during increment, which must be taken in account.

Obviously there is problem that content of directory can change during the loop execution, so actual loop might look much more complex.

Comment: That your example returns `1` is because you already used `a` in the range base for. So you don't explain what's wrong with `std::distance(fs::directory_iterator("."), fs::directory_iterator{} )`?

Comment: @t.niese  I know that, I forgot to add that bit. increment got sideeffect. Not much aside that depends of implementation, distance might be slower. This cannot be unwinded iby compiler because of run-time side-effect.

Comment: I get that a lot with mobile browsers, thanks anyway. I think, provider proxy and reduced polling rate  affect it too

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the POSIX API directly, which will about as fast and memory efficient you can get for a filesystem unaware approach (C++17). It counts '.' and '..' as well, you probably want to compensate for that.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> dir_entries(const char* path)
{
  DIR* dp{::opendir(path)};
  if (!dp)
  {
    // Alternatively, return -1 instead of an optional, throw an exception, etc.   
    // Jury it still out on this one :)
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  int entries{0};
  while (::readdir(dp))
    ++entries;

  ::closedir(dp);
  return entries;
}
```